# Apache HttpClient : Retry with failsafe results in 400 (bad request)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, retrypolicy, java-failsafe

I am using Apache `HttpClient` with [Failsafe](https://jodah.net/failsafe/) java library. Below is how the (pseudo) code looks like:

```
RetryPolicy<CloseableHttpResponse> policy = new RetryPolicy<>()
                .handleResultIf(/* Response code is 404 */)
                .withMaxRetries(5)
                .withDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

CloseableHttpResponse response = Failsafe.with(policy).get(() -> httpClient.execute(myRequest));
```

It's calling a test endpoint at `localhost` and I have mocked it to do the following:

- Return 404 for the first 3 requests
- Return 200 for the 4th request

Now, when I execute the above code, I see the following behavior:

1. HttpClient sends `get` request, it results in 404
2. As the response is `404`, retry policy kicks in and retries the request
3. Retried request **fails** with `400` **without** actually reaching the proxy
4. All the subsequent retries fail with `400`. The response doesn't have any body

I expect the request in step 2 to hit my mock, however, it fails without hitting it. Does `HttpClient` cache the response or tries to prevent the subsequent retries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was setting headers in the request with `addHeader` method before calling `execute` for `httpClient`. This resulted in requests with duplicate `Content-Type` and `Authorization` headers.

As these header values are certainly invalid, the requests resulted in `400` error without hitting the url.